# What will happen to my purchased apps after resetting my phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, store

I purchased a pack of apps from Microsoft Store. I want to know if I reset my phone for any reason, will I be able to use them again without repurchasing them?

I am talking here about

- Paid apps.
- Free apps with in-app purchases. Will its locked features be unlocked after I paid for them the next time I download the app or format my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all the apps you have purchased can be downloaded for free after a hard reset as long as you still sign in with the same Microsoft Account.

As for in-app purchases, this depends on the kind of IAP and how the developer has implemented it. If it's a single purchase (like removing ads) you should be able to just re-buy it for free.
If it's a consumable (like coins for a game) the developer will have store this Information somewhere in the cloud so he can restore it after a reinstall.

Answer (score -1):

Well that could be if you use the same phone.  Note however that if you use ( start with ) another phone the apps are lost.  Even if you sign in with the same Microsoft Account, and even if you transfer your micro-SD ( with the apps on it ) to the new phone.
Tested on 620, 630, 640.

Comment: If you sign in with the same Microsoft Account you certainly can download previously purchased apps for free, regardless what Windows phone you are using.